# Reloading values on apex component

Tags: apex, controller, visualforce-component

needs some help.

Am a beginner in learning Apex development in SalesForce and am stuck on following:

There are two components on one vf page:

```
<apex:page>
 <apex:composition>   
        <apex:define name="Some1">
                <c:component1 />            
        </apex:define>
        <apex:define name="Some2">          
                <c:c:component2 /> 
            </div>              
        </apex:define>
</apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```

Component1 has a controller with RemoteAction event, calling Component2 controller event and passing an Object.

```
Component2Controller details = new Component2Controller(object);
```

All is good but once that Component2 is loaded i cannot update values after Component1 controller calls it.

Component2Controller has:

```
public List lstDetails {get {
        if(object!= null){                              
            return getListDetails(object);
            }
        return lstDetails ;
    }set;}
```

listDetails is not null, but is never updated on view

Can you guys tell me how should do this?

Thank you all!